# Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 both freeze except you can still use keyboard and mouse

Tags: 12.04, unity, keyboard, mouse, screensaver

After a period of time which seems to be the same every time (although i have not timed it) everything on the desktop freezes, except for the keyboard and mouse.

1. I tried disabling everything in the power and screensaver options to stop it from going to sleep but that didn't fix it.
2. I tried installing xscreensaver to completely disable the unity screensaver but that didn't fix it either.
3. I have monitored the system temperatures and they haven't exceeded 55ºC

Syslog is as follows:

```
    Feb  7 07:39:43 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="1230" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Feb  7 07:40:34 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe anacron[27976]: Job `cron.daily' terminated (mailing output)
Feb  7 07:40:34 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe anacron[27976]: Can't find sendmail at /usr/sbin/sendmail, not mailing output
Feb  7 07:40:34 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe anacron[27976]: Job `cron.weekly' started
Feb  7 07:40:34 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe anacron[31777]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.weekly' to 2016-02-07
Feb  7 07:41:36 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe anacron[27976]: Job `cron.weekly' terminated
Feb  7 07:41:36 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe anacron[27976]: Normal exit (2 jobs run)
Feb  7 08:01:19 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe udevd[6370]: symlink '../../sdd' '/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:11.0-scsi-0:0:0:0.udev-tmp' failed: File exists
Feb  7 08:09:01 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe CRON[8862]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
Feb  7 08:13:24 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe avahi-daemon[1454]: Invalid response packet from host 192.168.1.10.
Feb  7 08:17:01 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe CRON[11441]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb  7 08:39:01 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe CRON[18656]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
Feb  7 09:06:21 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.196 on eth0 to 192.168.1.254 port 67
Feb  7 09:06:21 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.196 from 192.168.1.254
Feb  7 09:06:21 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe dhclient: bound to 192.168.1.196 -- renewal in 39627 seconds.
Feb  7 09:06:21 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe NetworkManager[1515]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed bound -> renew
Feb  7 09:06:21 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe NetworkManager[1515]: <info>   address 192.168.1.196
Feb  7 09:06:21 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe NetworkManager[1515]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
Feb  7 09:06:21 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe NetworkManager[1515]: <info>   gateway 192.168.1.254
Feb  7 09:06:21 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe NetworkManager[1515]: <info>   hostname 'BEN-PC-ETH'
Feb  7 09:06:21 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe NetworkManager[1515]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.1.254'
Feb  7 09:06:21 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe NetworkManager[1515]: <info>   domain name 'home.gateway'
Feb  7 09:06:22 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe dbus[1317]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Feb  7 09:06:22 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe dbus[1317]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Feb  7 09:09:01 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe CRON[28438]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
Feb  7 09:13:24 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe avahi-daemon[1454]: Invalid response packet from host 192.168.1.10.
Feb  7 09:17:01 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe CRON[31073]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb  7 09:37:36 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe udevd[5531]: symlink '../../sdb' '/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:11.0-scsi-0:0:0:0.udev-tmp' failed: File exists
Feb  7 09:39:01 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe CRON[6035]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
Feb  7 09:40:45 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe udevd[6543]: symlink '../../sdb' '/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:11.0-scsi-0:0:0:0.udev-tmp' failed: File exists
Feb  7 09:41:39 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe kernel: [41914.753206] show_signal_msg: 135 callbacks suppressed
Feb  7 09:41:39 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe kernel: [41914.753211] Watchdog[6888]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f3afe9a073e sp 00007f3af1f08690 error 6 in libcontent.so[7f3afe104000+11d5000]
Feb  7 09:41:55 ben-M4A79T-Deluxe kernel: [41931.193405] Watchdog[7135]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f61081c273e sp 00007f60fb72a690 error 6 in libcontent.so[7f6107926000+11d5000]
```

sudo lshw -short > ~/Desktop/hardware.txt

```
H/W path          Device     Class       Description
====================================================
                             system      System Product Name (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
/0                           bus         M4A79T Deluxe
/0/0                         memory      64KiB BIOS
/0/4                         processor   AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 965 Processor
/0/4/5                       memory      512KiB L1 cache
/0/4/6                       memory      2MiB L2 cache
/0/4/7                       memory      6MiB L3 cache
/0/3d                        memory      16GiB System Memory
/0/3d/0                      memory      4GiB DIMM DDR Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
/0/3d/1                      memory      4GiB DIMM DDR Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
/0/3d/2                      memory      4GiB DIMM DDR Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
/0/3d/3                      memory      4GiB DIMM DDR Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
/0/100                       bridge      RD790 Host Bridge
/0/100/2                     bridge      RX780/RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx0 port A)
/0/100/2/0                   display     Juniper XT [Radeon HD 5770]
/0/100/2/0.1                 multimedia  Juniper HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5700 Series]
/0/100/5                     bridge      RX780/RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port B)
/0/100/5/0                   bus         uPD720201 USB 3.0 Host Controller
/0/100/6                     bridge      RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port C)
/0/100/6/0        eth0       network     RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/7                     bridge      RX780/RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port D)
/0/100/7/0                   bus         VT6315 Series Firewire Controller
/0/100/c                     bridge      RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx1 port B)
/0/100/c/0        scsi2      storage     Series 8 12G SAS/PCIe 3
/0/100/c/0/0.0.0  /dev/sda   volume      7449GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/c/0/1.0.0             disk        WDC WD40EFRX-68W
/0/100/c/0/1.1.0             disk        WDC WD40EFRX-68W
/0/100/c/0/1.2.0             disk        WDC WD40EFRX-68W
/0/100/c/0/1.3.0             disk        WDC WD40EFRX-68W
/0/100/11                    storage     SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode]
/0/100/12                    bus         SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
/0/100/12.1                  bus         SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
/0/100/12.2                  bus         SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
/0/100/13                    bus         SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
/0/100/13.1                  bus         SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
/0/100/13.2                  bus         SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
/0/100/14                    bus         SBx00 SMBus Controller
/0/100/14.1                  storage     SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller
/0/100/14.2                  multimedia  SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
/0/100/14.3                  bridge      SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
/0/100/14.4                  bridge      SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
/0/100/14.4/6     wlan0      network     AR922X Wireless Network Adapter
/0/100/14.5                  bus         SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
/0/101                       bridge      Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
/0/102                       bridge      Family 10h Processor Address Map
/0/103                       bridge      Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
/0/104                       bridge      Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
/0/105                       bridge      Family 10h Processor Link Control
/0/1              scsi0      storage     
/0/1/0.0.0        /dev/sdb   disk        500GB WDC WD5000AADS-0
/0/1/0.0.0/1      /dev/sdb1  volume      100MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2      /dev/sdb2  volume      79GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/3      /dev/sdb3  volume      99GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/4      /dev/sdb4  volume      285GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/2              scsi1      storage     
/0/2/0.0.0        /dev/sdc   disk        2TB WDC WD20EARS-00M
/0/2/0.0.0/1      /dev/sdc1  volume      1863GiB EXT4 volume
/0/3              scsi3      storage     
/0/3/0.0.0        /dev/sdd   disk        500GB WDC WD5000AAKX-6
/0/3/0.0.0/1      /dev/sdd1  volume      95GiB EXT4 volume
/0/3/0.0.0/2      /dev/sdd2  volume      355GiB EXT4 volume
/0/3/0.0.0/3      /dev/sdd3  volume      15GiB Extended partition
/0/3/0.0.0/3/5    /dev/sdd5  volume      15GiB Linux swap / Solaris partition
```

It doesn't happen while I am using the pc but after a period of idle time it freezes.
My only safe option is to Ctrl + Alt + F1 and sudo init 6
Please help?

Comment: It would be useful if you provide time reference to correlate the logs with. I mean info like freeze from 7:42 to 8:00.

Comment: It's difficult to get a time reference.
Last night I closed all of the open applications but left it logged in and this morning it wasn't frozen.
I also thought 2 on Monday that it was firefox causing the issue but after using Chromium-browser it still did it.
There was an update for firefox lastnight so I dont know if that fixed it or not.

Comment: The info you posted doesn't tell me much. Maybe you'll get help from someone who's smarter. If you're not that lucky, pay attention to the time when the freezing happens. There are ring buffer logs at ` /var/log/dmesg*` which are more informative. You can read old ones this way `zcat /var/log/dmesg.1.gz`. You can try to investigate them and see if you can find anything. But as you'll see, they're very dense, hence the time gap is so precious. If you want to make the files public, remember they may contain vulnerable data such as firewall filtering. You may prefer to filter things out.

Comment: I think the dmesg logs get truncated to a certain size at archiving, so when the freeze happens, save the full current log when you go to the command line with Ctrl + Alt + F1 for future revision this way `dmesg > dm.full`

Comment: I have discovered that if you move the mouse or tap any key on the keyboard it wakes up as if asleep. However it takes about 2-5 minutes to wake up.