# System freezing at visual artifacts screen

Tags: 12.04, crash, system, visual-artifacts

My computer running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is freezing up quite often and the screen looks like this.
[image: System lock-up]
Only way to fix is to hard power down and restart.

What could be causing this?
What commands do I need to run to help assist with the diagnosis?

Answer (score 0):

Can you narrow it down to some possible problems? A little bit more information might be useful. If not i recommend you to use 'dmesg' command to find out if any of your hardware gives a warning or an error. Also you might want to explore inside of the /var/log/ for additional logging files.

Comment: I'll have a look when I get home from work.
So far I haven't been able to narrow it down to anything.

Comment: I get home from work and it's like it,
I transfer files from one location to another, it happens (It has done it quite often while doing this.)
Using find command with -exec cp file to location, quite often causes this issue.

Comment: Can you try the same actions in tty2?

Ctrl+Alt+F2 --> Execute the commands. Ctrl+Alt+F7 to go back to GNOME.

Comment: no cant access Ctrl+Alt+F2

Answer (score 0):

The repeating pattern of geometric visual artifacts combined with freezing looks looks like something that could be caused by a bad memory chip in a graphics card, but please ignore this answer if your computer does not have a graphics card. If you ever get repeating audio loops and a frozen screen together when playing an online video, that confirms it. If I saw this on my desktop computer, I would try temporarily removing the graphics card or swapping it with another graphics card.

For more information visit this webpage: [Diagnose video card problems by comparing with example corrupted screens](http://www.playtool.com/pages/artifacts/artifacts.html)

Comment: We can watch 1080p movies and not get this issue otherwise I would agree. I do have a spare so I could try this any way.
I was suspecting a RAM issue, as I commented above, if I move large volumes of data it happens but never while watching movies.

Comment: It may be related to this issue I was having earlier this year
http://askubuntu.com/questions/731588/ubuntu-12-04-and-14-04-both-freeze-except-you-can-still-use-keyboard-and-mouse

Comment: A RAM stick with a bad sector can cause that type of visual glitching too. btw the way a bad graphics card can also cause freezing when moving large volumes of data, for example when backing up files to an external hard drive. Illogical as this may seem, I had the exact same problem and switching the graphics card fixed it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a go this weekend and post an update after